# How do I use a Native Node JS Module (--experimental-modules) with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have the following Test Suite...

```
import Mocha from 'mocha';
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
(()=>{
    let mocha = new Mocha();
    mocha.addFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./tests/sampleTest.js'));
    mocha.run(failures => {
        console.log("Running Mocha");

        process.on('exit', () => {
            console.log("Ending Mocha");
            process.exit(failures ? 1 : 0);
        });
    });
})();
```

And the following test file...

```
const assert = require('assert');
describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
    });
  });
});
```

This works great, however, I want to convert it over to a module JS (.mjs) so I can import other modules in the test. I try this by changing the extension and making the code...

```
import assert from 'assert';
describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this I get...

`Must use import to load ES Module: **/src/test/js/webdriver/tests/sampleTest.mjs`

I also tried just importing it like this...

```
import Mocha from 'mocha';
import path from 'path';
import './tests/sampleTest.mjs';
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
(()=>{
    let mocha = new Mocha();
//    mocha.addFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./tests/sampleTest.mjs'));
    mocha.run(failures => {
        console.log("Running Mocha");

        process.on('exit', () => {
            console.log("Ending Mocha");
            process.exit(failures ? 1 : 0);
        });
    });
})();
```

But then I get...

> ReferenceError: describe is not defined

I also tried

```
import mocha from "mocha"
...
mocha.describe(...)
```

But that also did not work.

How do I load another module into mocha?

Comment: refer to http://jamesknelson.com/testing-in-es6-with-mocha-and-babel-6/

Comment: Again I don't want Babel involved. It is super easy with babel

Comment: By that mean I don't need the extra step of bringing back to es5 just to run tests. I would prefer they stay es6+ and use the native module loader

Comment: You could try `import { describe } from 'mocha'` in your test file

Comment: I tried that didn't work but I forget the error so I will try again and post

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround for now is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjs-mocha

I hope this link is suitable here cause npm does save packages forever. Feel free to refer to package docs and sources